# Strange behavior of javascript toExponential method

Tags: javascript, numbers, exponential

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential) says:

> If you use the toExponential() method for a numeric literal and the
>   numeric literal has no exponent and no decimal point, leave
>   whitespace(s) before the dot that precedes the method call to prevent
>   the dot from being interpreted as a decimal point.

However, when trying to use this method to a numeric literal (snippet below), I'm getting an error:

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

There should be no problem in interpreting the point as a decimal point, since there would be no digits after it.

Also, this code gave an error the first time I've run it on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/jobyem3f/). But now it's not giving any error. Strange!

What's going on here after all? Who's right? MDN's browser compatibility table says this method has had full support since long ago.

```js
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = 100 .toExponential();
document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = 100.toExponential();
```

```html
<span id='a'></span><br>
<span id='b'></span>
```

Comment: The whitespace works fine. You can also do `100..toExponential()`

Comment: @elclanrs Shouldn't the first span above have showed something?

Comment: Because your code fails to execute because of the syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a function on numbers like `100.toExponential()`, so you'll either have to add a whitespace or add another dot. The reason being that when working with numbers, JavaScript expects a decimal after the first dot... so by adding another dot then we tell JavaScript that the decimal part is empty and it can continue to the method.

```js
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = 100 .toExponential();
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = 100..toExponential();
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML = (100).toExponential();
```

```html
<span id="a"></span><br />
<span id="b"></span><br />
<span id="c"></span>
```

The code probably gave you an error on jsfiddle on the first run because there was that syntax error which most likely got automatically corrected when you saved the file for example.

Comment: If any of the lines produces an error, the whole snippet will break, which is not how JavaScript usually behaves (the lines before the error are normally executed). I think that's the source of my confusion. Thank you!